# CSS id-element overwriting its child's definition

Tags: css, parent, overwrite

```
#top a {
  color: #C6D6CA;
  margin: 0 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mainlink a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

.mainlink div sits somewhere in the #top one. Why's that the #top a (parental) definition of margin overwrites the one set in .mainlink a? How to change that behaviour?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML or a sample of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it by changing your rules:

```
#top a {}
#top .mainlink a {}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called selector specifity. See also: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Comment: Specifically, `#id` selectors have higher specificity than `.class` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS "cascades" the color will apply to any of the element's children. You'll need to specify the color for the child and possibly need to add an "!important" to the end of the property declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Named ids have a higher precedence than classes when the style sheets are cascaded.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

You can use `margin: 0 !important` to force the override.

Answer (score 0):

The `#top a` selector has more [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) than `.mainlink a`.  ID selectors *greatly* increase the specificity of a selector.

Each ID increase the specificity of the selector by a factor of 100. Each class increases the specificity by a factor of 10.

That being the case, I'd either:

A. Replace the ID with a class *or*
B. Add an ID to the second selector.